# Method which accepts both EventHandler<T> and EventHandler

Tags: c#, generics

Assuming you have a method like this

```
private void FireEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventHandler, T eventArgs, string name)
{
    var handler = eventHandler;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sending event {0}", name));
        handler(this, eventArgs);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnconnectedEventException(name);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite/overload/extend this method so it accepts both `EventHandler<T> and EventHandler` (`eventArgs` could e.g. be `EventArgs.empty` in the latter case)?

The current solution is this additional method:

```
private void FireEvent(EventHandler eventHandler, string name)
{
    var handler = eventHandler;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sending event {0}", name));
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnconnectedEventException(name);
    }
}
```

But this involves copying every line of the implementation with one minor difference, which kills me on the inside. There surely must be a better solution.

Note: The second example fires an `EventHandler`, not an `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. The two types cannot be converted to each other since they are unrelated delegates.

Comment: can you just call FireEvent<object>() ?? Easy enough to write a wrapper function without the <T> generic argument and just have it call your generic method using object only and EventArgs.Empty.

Comment: Have you tried just adding a method with the signature desired? If so, please post the errors you got (if any).

Comment: Delegates do not have inheritance, so `EventHandler<T>` and `EventHandler` are fundamentally different types that can't be handled with one method. But for the same reason, there's no problem with having a `FireEvent(EventHandler eventHandler, EventArgs eventArgs string name)` overload. If you really though it worthwhile to separate out the logic, you could extract the `handler(this, eventArgs)` call as an `Action`, but this would come at a loss of efficiency.

Comment: Since the type of the `eventArgs` argument (the `T`) would be `EventArgs`, declare the event handler as `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. I also second the suggestion of just using a separate method. Just don't try to use one method to do two separate things just because they appear similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the shortest correct solution that does not copy code or ignore `EventArgs` is:

```
private void FireEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventHandler, T eventArgs, string name)
{
    if (eventHandler == null) throw new UnconnectedEventException(name);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sending event {0}", name));
    eventHandler(this, eventArgs);
}

private void FireEvent(EventHandler eventHandler, EventArgs eventArgs, string name) =>
    FireEvent(eventHandler == null ? null : new EventHandler<EventArgs>(eventHandler), eventArgs, name);
```

(The standard pattern of first assigning the event handler to a local variable for thread safety is not necessary here, since we've already implicitly copied it as part of the method call.)